# PySpark3 no attribute 'tzinfo' error when parsing yyyyMMddhhmmss into TimestampType()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have this csv file (test.csv) containing the following:

---

```
COLUMN_STRING;COLUMN_INT;COLUMN_TIMESTAMP
String_Value_1;123456;20131226224757
String_Value_2;234567;20141227234858
String_Value_3;345678;20151228214555
```

---

I'm trying to import the 3rd column timestamp yyyyMMddhhmmss into a TimestampType() with the following code:

---

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
data = sc.textFile('test.csv')\
              .map(lambda s: s.split(";"))\
              .filter(lambda v: v[0] != 'COLUMN_STRING') \
              .map(lambda v: (v[0], int(v[1]), v[2]))

schema = StructType([StructField('COLUMN_STRING',StringType(),False),
             StructField('COLUMN_INT',IntegerType(),False),
             StructField('COLUMN_TIMESTAMP',TimestampType(),False)])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.take(2)
```

---

And when I run it in PySpark3 on a Spark 1.6.3 Cluster (HDP3.5), I get an error about the "'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'"...

This is a simplified example. I have to find how to import such yyyyMMddhhmmss as is in a TimestampType() without altering the original data, because this is a simplified test (my actual data is massive, so modifying source is NOT an option).

I included the error message below.

Any help appreciated / Thanks, MT

---

An error occurred while calling

```
z:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.0.0.13): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in toInternal
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 435, in toInternal
    return self.dataType.toInternal(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 190, in toInternal
    seconds = (calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple()) if dt.tzinfo
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1433)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1421)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1642)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1601)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1831)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1844)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1857)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$takeAndServe$1.apply$mcI$sp(python.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$takeAndServe$1.apply(python.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$takeAndServe$1.apply(python.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython$.takeAndServe(python.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe(python.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in toInternal
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 435, in toInternal
    return self.dataType.toInternal(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 190, in toInternal
    seconds = (calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple()) if dt.tzinfo
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 306, in take
    self._jdf, num)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.0.0.13): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in toInternal
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 435, in toInternal
    return self.dataType.toInternal(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 190, in toInternal
    seconds = (calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple()) if dt.tzinfo
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1433)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1421)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1642)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1601)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1831)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1844)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1857)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$takeAndServe$1.apply$mcI$sp(python.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$takeAndServe$1.apply(python.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$takeAndServe$1.apply(python.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython$.takeAndServe(python.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe(python.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in toInternal
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 435, in toInternal
    return self.dataType.toInternal(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 190, in toInternal
    seconds = (calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple()) if dt.tzinfo
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Schema should reflect the types you have so if you want to use RDD you should parse it first:

```
.map(lambda v: (
  v[0], int(v[1]), datetime.datetime.strptime(v[2], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))
```